# How to create folder and upload file inside openshift?

Tags: upload, openshift, server, openshift-client-tools

I'm using `rhc client tools` for openshift. and i want to upload it `PhantomJS`. So, I've Executable file and now i want to upload into my openshift server, So please let me know. How can i create folder? and how to upload it? I googled but fully confused with `${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}`.

*Help would be appreciated!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows you can use winscp to do what you want.  Use the equivalent  for Mac or Linux. You will want to upload to the DATA directory in your gear. The data directory is already created for you.

Comment: One thing i'd like to know.. Should i need to download `Linux file for PhantomJS` inside Openshift? Please let me know?

Comment: Openshift requires the Linux version of phantomjs

Comment: Sir, I'd accept your answer.. one thing i need to know.. Can you please tell me how to install `Ghostdriver` inside Openshift? :(

Comment: Never used it. I just use phantoms and casperjs.

Comment: Sir.. But there is a problem with `CasperJS` ..It doesn't support the latest version of `PhantomJS` .. So how did you managed it?

Comment: What support problems are you having? Both are working fine for me.

Comment: Sir... Are you using both the latest version of `phantomjs` and `casperjs` ..? Please let me know sir?

Comment: I'm using phantoms 1.9.7 and Casperjs 1.1.0 beta 3

Comment: Sir.. This is my last question.. What IDE do you use for it?.. Using `cmd` or `terminal` makes us sick to compile our program. please sir.. What IDE do you use?

Comment: Sir but it is for Python. How do you use it with?

Comment: My python code calls phantomjs with a casperjs script. The output is a text file which I can manipulate with python.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks :) Please get in touch sir :)